# Is it possible to access keys in same array - PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Good day, i have an array as such:

```
$cart = [
   'id' => 1,
   'item_name' => 'sample',
   'quantity' => 20,
   'price' => 50,
];
```

i tried doing this:

```
'total' => $cart['quantity'] * $cart['price']
```

i get an undefined index error.

Is there any way to achieve this.

Note: the `'total'` key is in the same array `$cart`.

Comment: You first need to define the array before you can access it. So define it first and after it you can add your `total` element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try this it will work::

```
<?php
$cart = [
   'id' => 1,
   'item_name' => 'sample',
   'quantity' => 20,
   'price' => 50,
];
$cart['total'] = $cart['quantity'] * $cart['price'];
echo "<pre>";
print_r($cart);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

after you see the result please remove the echo part as your need.

Answer (score 4):

You can't access indexes not already created

Try it this way

```
$cart = [
   'id' => 1,
   'item_name' => 'sample',
   'quantity' => 20,
   'price' => 50,
];

$cart['total'] = $cart['quantity'] * $cart['price'];
```